# PHP Shell_Exec webpage issue

Tags: php, shell-exec

created a webpage button to launch a stress test to backend server via PHP.  Button executes script and then I get a timeout issue.  I am assuming that webpage is waiting for output, but the script will run for 2-5 minutes.  I am wanting it to run and either redirect to same page or run stress with no output etc.  I have tried a redirect but didn't work, I assume still waiting for the output before the redirect.

```
<?php
#run stress script
$output = shell_exec('stress --cpu 4 --timeout 120 2>&1');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must run this task in background. Your output will be saved into `output.txt`

```
shell_exec("stress --cpu 4 --timeout 120 > output.txt &");
```